# google-play-services-maps:17.0.0 is not working even with default project Android Studio created

Tags: android, google-maps

Please help me...

I want to create a project based on Google Maps. But after building gradle in Android Studio, The following error occurs:

ERROR:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

When i clicked on the 'Install Repository and ...' then this message appear:

Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"

NOTE:
Gradle work online mode.
I went to Setting and Android SDK then downloaded google play services.. but it is not working for me.
I also set up a proxy.

**EDIT:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

root gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add your build.gradle code

Comment: @Android_id it's done.

Answer (score 0):

After much effort, I was able to solve the problem.
Strange as it may seem, the problem was solved by manually adjusting the proxy.

thanks all.

Comment: I would suggest to elaborate the asnwer for the community. Thanks!

Comment: @karandhillon Of course. At the first i downloaded Google play services from SDK tools then I Sync Gradle but it did not succeed and Failed to resolve this dependency. I tried to install it by clicking on the link but it didn't work.  I finally set manual proxy configuration and succeeded. NOTE: Auto-detect proxy maybe not work.